# Bison Grammar %type and %token

Tags: grammar, bison, flex-lexer, yacc

Why is it that I have to use `$<nVal>4` explicitly in the below grammar snippet?

I thought the `%type <nVal> expr` line would remove the need so that I can simply put `$4`?

Is it not possible to use a different definition for `expr` so that I can?

```
%union
{
  int   nVal;
  char *pszVal;
}

%token <nVal>   tkNUMBER
%token <pszVal> tkIDENT
%type  <nVal>   expr

%%

for_statement : tkFOR 
                tkIDENT   { printf( "I:%s\n", $2 );  }
                tkEQUALS 
                expr      { printf( "A:%d\n", $<nVal>4 );    }  // Why not just $4?
                tkTO 
                expr      { printf( "B:%d\n", $<nVal>6 );    }  // Why not just $6?
                step-statement 
                list 
                next-statement;

expr : tkNUMBER { $$ = $1; }
;
```

**Update** following rici's answer. This now works a treat:

```
for_statement : tkFOR 
                tkIDENT   { printf( "I:%s\n", $2 );  }
                tkEQUALS 
                expr      { printf( "A:%d\n", $5 /* $<nVal>5 */ );    }
                tkTO 
                expr      { printf( "A:%d\n", $8 /* $<nVal>8 */ );    }
                step-statement 
                list 
                next-statement;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is it that I have to use `$<nVal>4` explicitly in the below grammar snippet?

Actually, you should use `$5` if you want to refer to the `expr`. `$4` is the `tkEQUALS`,  which has no declared type, so any use must be explicitly typed.  `$3` is the previous midrule action, which has no value since `$$` is not assigned in that action.

By the same logic, the second `expr` is `$8`; `$6` is the second midrule action, which also has no value (and no type).

See the [Bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Using-Mid_002dRule-Actions):

> The mid-rule action itself counts as one of the components of the rule. This makes a difference when there is another action later in the same rule (and usually there is another at the end): you have to count the actions along with the symbols when working out which number *n* to use in `$n`.

Comment: I get it - a "mid rule action" is the curly brace "blobs" that are appearing in the middle of the rule, rather than appearing at the end. So if I'd had one rule at the very end, all of my original numberings would have worked. Using mid-rule actions, I need to include the mid-rule blobs in the numbering.